# What is the reason that spring boot only queries appear in the hibernate log and no mapped value values are seen?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

As you can see, only query statements appear in the log? I can't see the actual matching values on the values??

If you test insert, the value goes into the table well...

I even asked Chatgpt to add settings, but there's no change... What should I do?? Please help me

[image]

Comment: Because there are no parameters. That is the query that gets send to the server which does the replacement of the values.

Answer (score 0):

Logging SQL in Spring boot 3 with Hibernate 6:

```
logging:
  level:
    sql: debug
    org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind: trace
```

Comment: I applied the method you suggested, but it doesn't seem to work well. Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

implementation `'com.github.gavlyukovskiy:p6spy-spring-boot-starter:1.9.0'`

Resolved by adding one line of dependency injection code above to gradle!